# Right-regular grammar conversion to NFA: production rule with only one variable on right side

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata, formal-grammars

I'm trying to convert a right regular grammar to an NFA.
I understand that I need to create a state for every variable and add transitions according to the production rules.

But what if there is a production rule where there is only a single variable on the right side and nothing else?

Example: $A \rightarrow B$

Would that simply mean, that there should be an $\varepsilon$ transition from A to B?